# How to get bits of an 8-bit binary column array into separate columns or separate arrays?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bit

Consider the following array:

```
>> a=[26;94;32];
>> b=dec2bin(a,8);
>> c=str2num(b);
>> d1=bitget(c,1);
>> d2=bitget(c,2);
>> d3=bitget(c,3);
>> d4=bitget(c,4);
>> d5=bitget(c,5);
>> d6=bitget(c,6);
>> d7=bitget(c,7);
>> d8=bitget(c,8);
>> e1=bitget(a,1);
>> e2=bitget(a,2);
>> e3=bitget(a,3);
>> e4=bitget(a,4);
>> e5=bitget(a,5);
>> e6=bitget(a,6);
>> e7=bitget(a,7);
>> e8=bitget(a,8);
```

I expect these results from the code:

```
d1 = e1  
d2 = e2
d3 = e3  
d4 = e4
d5 = e5
d6 = e6
d7 = e7
d8 = e8
```

But actually we have the results:

```
d1 = e1  
d2 = e2
d3 = e3  
d4 != e4
d5 != e5
d6 != e6
d7 != e7
d8 != e8
```

Could you please tell me why?

In fact I want to separately write bits of b or c in different columns of an array or in different column arrays and the use it in bitplane slicing.
I don't want to use `bitget` directly ( It's a homework assignment of my image processing class and the professor has emphasized on not using matlab image processing functions directly). Could you please tell me how can I do that without slowing down the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically to possibilities to do what you want.

The first [mentioned by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015299/2605073):

```
b = dec2bin(a,8)
c = b-'0'
```

will return:

```
c =

     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

But this is not how Matlab internally works with bit arrays, instead it assumes a "mirrored" orientation of bits.

To achieve that you could just use [**`de2bi`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html):

```
c = de2bi(a,8)
```

which will give you:

```
c =

     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

These arrays are now suitable for the function `bitget`, which also works with this "mirrored" orientation. That is why you got wrong results.

So for the second solution the comparison works fine:

```
d6 = c(:,6)
e6 = bitget(a,6)

d6 =

     0
     1
     0


e6 =

     0
     1
     0
```

Unfortunately `de2bi` requires the **Communications System toolbox**, if you don't have it you need to adjust Divakars solution to:

```
b = dec2bin(a,8)
c = fliplr(b-'0')
```

Final comparison:

```
e = [ bitget(a,1),bitget(a,2),bitget(a,3),bitget(a,4), ...    
      bitget(a,5),bitget(a,6),bitget(a,7),bitget(a,8) ]
comp = all( c == e ,3 )

comp =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Also one needs `Communications System Toolbox` for using `de2bi`. Kool tool that one though!

Answer (score 1):

Bits of `b` into a double array? Try this -

```
c = b-'0'
```